# Discrepancies in Plupload UI Widget user interface and generated html when using up to date jQuery and jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, symfony, plupload

### INTRODUCTION

In order to upload multiple files to the server I am using:

1. Symfony v3.2.8
2. [OneUpUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle)
3. [OneUpFlysystemBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle)
4. [Plupload file uploading library](http://www.plupload.com) v2.3.1 `jQuery UI Widget` version
5. [Plupload UI Widget Demo](http://www.plupload.com/examples/ui)

### TARGET

I would like that `Plupload` UI design in my project looked the same as in example on project's official homepage (5th link in the introduction section).

### PROBLEM

At the moment `Plupload` widget in my personal project looks similar, but not identical to the example in project's official homepage.

Screenshots

- of Plupload UI widget (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GRj1.jpg)
- of Plupload widget in my project ([http://imgur.com/RkBjOdg](https://imgur.com/RkBjOdg))

NOTE: There is some extra padding on the sides of every button (2nd image)!

*Sadly differences are not only cosmetic - it seems that official example is producing different HTML (please look below for example in CODE section).*

### QUESTION

How can I make UI look like example in official homepage - with correct padding and margin for buttons?

### CODE

Excerpt code block from demo on `plupload` homepage (http://www.plupload.com/examples/ui)

```
<a class="plupload_button plupload_add ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" id="uploader_browse" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="z-index: 1;">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">Add Files</span>
</a>
```

Excerpt code block from `plupload-2.3.1` downloaded from projects homepage

```
<a class="plupload_button plupload_add ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" id="uploader_browse" role="button" style="z-index: 1;">
    <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>
    Add Files
</a>
```

### FINALLY

What am I missing?

### UPDATE

I traced it down to different `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` versions used in `plupload` demo page and my project.

- JSFiddle of `plupload v2.3.1` demo with `jQuery v1.9.1` and `jQuery-UI v1.9.2` [demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mL5sx17j/3/)
- JSFiddle of `plupload v2.3.1` demo with `jQuery v3.2.1` and `jQuery-UI v1.12.1` [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/50tc65wr/3/)

As anyone can see - there are discrepancies not only visual, but also in generated code (see CODE section for excerpts or look at DEMO 1 and DEMO 2 and compare code for buttons in both).

It seems that something is amiss with `plupload` code in case when one uses it with up to date `jQuery` and `jQuery-UI`.